# add indicator for pageviewer which shows only after the second fragment?

Tags: java, android

How to add pageviewer indicator for a class which slides more than 3 fragments,
and the indicator should be displayed only after the second fragment slides. The first fragment doesnt need an indicator can any one help me  to implement that.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the relevant source code for this class that you're modifying? And be more specific about the trouble that you're having?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some library to display an indicator. Then you should implement [`OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and hide/show the indicator based on the position of your `ViewPager`.